# How can i calculate how much i need to scroll

Tags: jquery, css

i'v been scratching my head for two hours in trying to figure out whats the algorithm to scroll so that the selected item will be in the middle.

So i have a couple of variables and i dont know what to do with them
basically i have a playlist that u can select song to play by going up and down on your key keyboard
and the track changes, each time it changes i need to scroll

here is my variables:

```
var playlistContainer = $('.playlist').height(); // playlist container with overflow auto - 400px;
var listItemHeight    = $('.item:first').outerHeight(); // getting a list item height. - 30px;
var currentItemScrollTop = $('.item_current').position().top; // the current item scroll position.
var listLength  = $('li').length;

$('.playlist').animate({
  scrollTop: // have no idea what the algorithm is - i need the '.item_current' to be in the middle when possible.
}, 'slow');
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: if you set up a small fiddle of what you have I can fix it for you....I did something similar a few weeks ago..

Comment: also if the cells have a fixed heigth you can animate += cellHeight  or -= cellheight if you only need the next and prev element...

Comment: @pixelass there you go, http://jsfiddle.net/T8Fg5/ thanks.
and i did what u said about += cellHeight and that doesnt keep the selected element in the middle when possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

----------UPDATED VERSION----------

http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/VVVR4/8/

```
$(window).keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        fromTop = $('.selected').position().top;
        if (!$('.playlist li:last-child').hasClass('selected')) {
            if (fromTop >= 160) {
                $('.playlist').animate({
                    scrollTop: '+=32px'
                }, 200);
            }
            $('.selected').removeClass('selected').next().addClass('selected');
        }
        return false;
    } else if (e.keyCode == 38) {
        fromTop = $('.selected').position().top;
        if (!$('.playlist li:first-child').hasClass('selected')) {
            if (fromTop <= 160) {
                $('.playlist').animate({
                    scrollTop: '-=32px'
                }, 200);
            }
            $('.selected').removeClass('selected').prev().addClass('selected');
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: a combination of both...  http://jsfiddle.net/pixelass/VVVR4/7/   this way it will always force the selected element to the middle if the list's height allows it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [scrollTo](http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/) plugin to directly scroll to a specific element

Comment: that's my last option, because i don't like getting a plugin with 500+ lines for something that can be done with 5+ lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript's built-in `element.scrollIntoView(align)` function. But it does not have an option that can middle align your element on the view-port. It can scroll so that your element is at the top or bottom of the view-port, depending on whether the align param is true or false. If scrolling into 'view'  will do for your requirement, this is the most light-weight solution i believe.